# Hive-JDBC : No row found exception while fetching data from hive table through Hive-JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I have used the below code to connect to hive database. First part describes the table and second part executes a select query. The Select query runs fine, but does not fetch any row.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000", "mapr", "mapr");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName1 = "default.newEmployee";
        // describe table
        String sql = null;

        sql = "describe " + tableName1;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }

        // select * query
        sql = "select name from " + tableName1;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Complete");
        System.out.println("reslut "+res.getBoolean(0));
    }
}
```

When I login to hive and do a select, I get more than a million rows.
Anyone please suggest, If I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Could you show the exception message?

Comment: Can you change the line `System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));` for this one `System.out.println(res.getString(0) + "\t" + res.getString(1));`?

Comment: @JaimeCr Running: describe default.newEmployee
name string
Running: select name from default.newEmployee limit 1
Complete
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No row found.
 at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getColumnValue(HiveBaseResultSet.java:399)
Basically, describe works fine. System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2))  This prints the 1st and 2nd element from the response of describe ,ie, Column Name and its data type. Issue occurs when I fetch data using Select

Comment: If the index starts with 1, can you try `System.out.println("reslut "+res.getBoolean(1));` instead of `System.out.println("reslut "+res.getBoolean(0));`?

Comment: @JaimeCr
I tried System.out.println("reslut "+res.getBoolean(1));
But got the exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
 exception
Issue that i see here is that the resultset is empty.

Comment: Can you check if, before that statement, `res.next()` returns true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem. Instead of making a hive-jdbc connection, I used Runtime.exec method in java and it worked.

Runtime.exec("hive", "-e","Query");

I have still not figured out why the hive-jdbc connection gives error when query a table to fetch data. Why the metastore operation like "desc tablename" works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

After spending **way** too much time with a very similar problem: you must fetch the rows of your result set, even if it is only one row:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getResultSet();

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```